# Mapping a Point to latitude and longitude with mapstruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have this Model:

```
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_hotel")
public class THotel {
    private String name;
    private Point coordinates;
}
```

And I want this DTO

```
public class HotelDTO {
    private String nome;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
}
```

How do I map with mapstruct the two?

Comment: do you know how to set `latitude` and `longitude` to `Point` without mapping - for example with constructor or whatever else?

Comment: I can solve changing the Point coordinates to double latitude and double longitude but I would try to do it with custom mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have mapstruct pass additional arguments on to following mapping actions. In this case I've marked the additional fields as context (`org.mapstruct.Context`) fields, so that they will not automatically be used for mapping into THotel:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface THotelMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "nome", target = "name")
    @Mapping(source = ".", target = "coordinates")
    THotel mapToEntity(HotelDTO dto, @Context PrecisionModel precisionModel, @Context int SRID);

    @Mapping(source = "name", target = "nome")
    @Mapping(source = "coordinates.y", target = "latitude")
    @Mapping(source = "coordinates.x", target = "longitude")
    HotelDTO mapToDto(THotel tHotel);

    default Point toPoint(HotelDTO dto, @Context PrecisionModel precisionModel, @Context int SRID) {
        return new Point(new Coordinate(dto.getLongitude(), dto.getLatitude()), precisionModel, SRID);
    }
}
```

Or you can do [as Egor mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70939667/mapping-a-point-to-latitude-and-longitude-with-mapstruct#answer-70941583) and then use default values:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface THotelMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "nome", target = "name")
    @Mapping(source = ".", target = "coordinates")
    THotel mapToEntity(HotelDTO dto);

    @Mapping(source = "name", target = "nome")
    @Mapping(source = "coordinates.y", target = "latitude")
    @Mapping(source = "coordinates.x", target = "longitude")
    HotelDTO mapToDto(THotel tHotel);

    default Point toPoint(HotelDTO dto) {
        return new Point( new Coordinate( dto.getLongitude(), dto.getLatitude() ), new PrecisionModel(), 4326 );
    }
}
```

Also I noticed that the Point constructor was marked deprecated, so here is a version without that constructor:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface THotelMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "nome", target = "name")
    @Mapping(source = ".", target = "coordinates")
    THotel mapToEntity(HotelDTO dto, @Context GeometryFactory geomFactory);

    @Mapping(source = "name", target = "nome")
    @Mapping(source = "coordinates.y", target = "latitude")
    @Mapping(source = "coordinates.x", target = "longitude")
    HotelDTO mapToDto(THotel tHotel);

    default Point toPoint(HotelDTO dto, @Context GeometryFactory geomFactory) {
        return geomFactory.createPoint( new Coordinate( dto.getLongitude(), dto.getLatitude() ) );
    }
}
```

ps. I do hope that I didn't get [the longitude/latitude to x/y mixed up, but you can read about that here.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/does-y-mean-latitude-and-x-mean-longitude-in-every-gis-software)

Comment: I am trying this too but get compile error : error: No property named "coordinates.y" exists in source parameter(s).

Comment: Where are you using topoint method?

Comment: the `@Mapping(source =".", target = "coordinates")` will cause MapStruct to use the `toPoint` method. Because the methods signature matches the wanted conversion.

Comment: SO thats only used when going from DTO to entity?

Comment: yes, for the other way around there are two mapping annotations in the example: `@Mapping(source = "coordinates.y", target = "latitude")` and `@Mapping(source = "coordinates.x", target = "longitude")`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get deep into `org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point` class, but I hope it will help. Assume `Point.java` looks like:

```
public class Point {
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    // constructors and getters/setters present here
}
```

In this case mapper will look like:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface THotelMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "nome", target = "name")
    @Mapping(expression = "java(toPoint(dto))", target = "coordinates")
    THotel mapToEntity(HotelDTO dto);

    @Mapping(source = "name", target = "nome")
    @Mapping(expression = "java(tHotel.getCoordinates().getLatitude())", target = "latitude")
    @Mapping(expression = "java(tHotel.getCoordinates().getLongitude())", target = "longitude")
    HotelDTO mapToDto(THotel tHotel);

    default Point toPoint(HotelDTO dto) {
        // here you need to set latitude and longitude to Point some how
        return new Point(dto.getLatitude(),dto.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

Comment: the point is that there is no way to set latitude and longitude in Point except from doing that in the constructor, that takes also other parameters Point(Coordinate coordinate, PrecisionModel precisionModel, int SRID) https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Point.html